# Was King David a Muslim?

Tags: history, prophets, judaism, prophet-dawud

Someone mentioned, in a comment on one of my previous questions, that Muslims believe that King David was a Muslim.

Is this indeed the generally held belief across the Muslim world?

How can this be? David was the king of Israel, from the Tribe of Judah, wrote commentary on the Torah and led the Jewish people. Also there is no evidence he was ever in Mecca. If he was Muslim, how can you explain all the historical contradictions?

Comment: Please read a little bit about Islam before asking your questions: http://discover.islamway.net/articles.php?article_id=2 has a section on the other messengers and prophets from God that Islam requires belief in. Also http://islam.about.com/od/prophets/p/prophets.htm

Comment: Muslim doesn't refer only to the current generation of Muslims. It's a universal religion and covers all those who were before us. Until the advent of Islam, all those who lived and believed in the previous religions were Muslims(Submitters to God). But after Islam all those religions became abrogated and people were asked to follow the new text brought by the Prophet Muhammad(PUBH).

Comment: @Noah so everyone following the Torah - like King David - were actually Muslims. But then Muhammad (PBUH) came with a new text from God and asked people to follow it. And those that stuck with the original word from God are no longer Muslims. Am I understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 15):

It is a common misconception that Muhammad somehow "invented" Islam.  Rather, the term "Muslim" means one who submits himself to God.  King David, who ruled the kingdom of Israel under God's command while still submitting to His authority, was as much a Muslim as Muhammad was.

It has nothing at all to do with being in Mecca.

Comment: According to that explanation, Jews, Christians, and others who submit to God, would also be referred to as "Muslims", would they not? Why do Muslims refer to people from these groups as infidels?

Comment: @Curious1 If they truly submit to God, then yes they would by definition be Muslims.

Comment: @Curious1 To truly submit to God, you have to believe in Islam. You can't say you're truly submitting to God when believing in a religion that God doesn't want you to. In the time of King David (PBUH), his religion was the truth. So he really *was* submitting to God. Over time his teachings were corrupted and nowadays the only Muslims are those who follow the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). Similarly, during the time of Jesus (PBUH), the only Muslims were those who accepted/followed Jesus; and the same holds for all prophets of God. They all came to correct the true message from God.

Comment: @Erciyes but the Prophet Muhammad was not alive in the time of King David. How would David know to follow him?

Comment: @Curious1, He followed the commands of God, doing so in itself means he submitted to God, i.e. became a Muslim

Answer (score 7):

King David, also known as Dawood (peace be upon him), was one of the great Prophets of Allah, and he is mentioned in the Quran.  And as is known all Prophets came with the same message, and that was Islam, though the practices may defer according to their times their message is theologically the same.  Furthermore, Dawood (peace and blessings be upon him) was a Prophet of Bani Isra'eel, and being in Makkah has nothing to do with being Muslim.

Comment: There's a hadith that says all the Prophets (may peace and blessings be upon them) after Ibrahim (Abraham, may peace be upon him) did Hajj (which means going to Mecca), but I don't remember the authenticity of the hadith.

Answer (score 0):

To be a Muslim is to submit to God and do NOT associate anything or anyone with God and believe in or accept all of  profits and messengers .
From Adam (mpbh) to Muhammad (mpbh)
It's not complicated at all

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to read in the old testament of the bible i believe the psalms where david speaks about being in the hills of his fathers house at bacca. This is one of the ancient names of the holy city mecca

Comment: you may consider [How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

David was not a Muslim.. David was a Jew from the tribe of Judah and the Son of Jesse the King of Israel. Judaism and Islam are two completely distinct Religions. To be a Jew at the time of David meant to observe all the Jewish laws in the Torah all 613 commandments.
David, Moses, Jesus, Abraham, Isaac were not Muslims nor was Adam Job and Noah

Comment: You really made a point with your answer but try to bring on more references and also take time to check [answer]

Answer (score -1):

No king David was not Muslim neither was he Arab and definitely he was not an ishmaelite.

Comment: We appreciate your question about try to bring on more referencesto support your answer and you can also check on [answer] for more information

Comment: This doesn't reflect the Muslim perspective.

Answer (score -2):

Quran and old testament are more or less same ....after (son of God) Jesus Christ was born ,some ppl follow Jesus Christ as their Savior so they have been called Christian and some group of ppl follow prophet Mohammed then they are called Islam ... before all these things.. there is no Islam or no Christians and there is no separation Among the ppl ....there is only one God, he is the Creator of all ....Amen